# Prove the Series Converges or Diverges: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5+2n}{(1+2n^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5+2n}{(1+2n^2)^2}$$

How would I even do this to find if this converges or diverges? I tried doing the Telescoping series test but it just got really confusing.

I got as far as this using partial fraction decomposition:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5}{1+n^2} + \frac{2n-5n^2}{(1+2n^2)^2}$$

$$Sequence: (\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{3}),(1-\frac{16}{81}),(\frac{1}{2}
-\frac{29}{361}),...$$

I could really use some step by step instructions on how to do this one. Nothing seems to cancel out at all so I felt like I did it wrong. Did I even pick the right test to do it? This was on a quiz I took today so a thorough explanation wouldn't get me any points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{5+2n}{(1+2n^2)^2} \sim \frac{1}{2n^3}
$$ then use the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: How did you choose the $$\frac{1}{n^3}$$?

Comment: @England The numerator is equivalent to $2n$ ($5$ becomes negligible compared to $2n$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$) The denominator is equivalent to $(2n^2)^2$

Comment: @England You have, as $n$ tends to $\infty$, $$ \frac{5+2n}{(1+2n^2)^2}\sim \frac{2n}{(2n^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2n^3}$$

Comment: So as a rule of thumb you can ignore the number being added to the 2n (or a variation of it) as long as it doesn't have an exponent or anything?

Comment: @England Exactely!

Comment: @England It's not just a rule of thumb. There are ways to formalize it and it makes dealing with sequences and series much easier.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Farnight Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{5+2n}{\left(1+2n^{2}\right)^{2}}\leq\frac{5}{4}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{4}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{3}}=\frac{5}{4}\zeta\left(4\right)+\frac{1}{2}\zeta\left(3\right)\approx1.9534.
 $$

Comment: Solid answer!  +1 ...

Comment: What does the symbol `ζ` mean?

Comment: @wallyk It's the Riemann Zeta function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

$g(n)=(5+2n)/(1+2n^2)^2=n^{-3}(2+5n^{-1})/(2+n^{-2})^2=n^{-3}f(n)$  where $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=1/2$. So for all sufficiently large $n$ we have  $0<g(n)<n^{-3}$. There are many ways to show that $\sum_nn^{-s}$ converges for $s>1$ : e.g. Integral test, or Cauchy condensation test. And so $\sum_ng(n)$ converges by the comparison test.